# Error in typescript file property selectpicker does not exist on type IInstance

Tags: jquery, typescript, angular2-forms, bootstrap-selectpicker

Using Bootstrap-select to create group by multi select drop down with search enable 
facing the following error 
Property 'selectpicker' does not exist on type IInstance

Environment:
Typescript 2.2
angular 2.0
Jquery 2.2.4
Jquery-ts 2.1.1

[please find the attached image which contain error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0YIk.jpg)

Comment: Your not referencing the bootstrap datepicker, before you use it.

Answer (score 1):

Install the typings for `bootstrap-select` and make sure the dependencies `jquery`, `bootstrap` and  `bootstrap-select` are imported in your code to prevent any runtime errors:

```
npm install --save-dev @types/bootstrap-select
```

Comment: Thank you, how to add @types/bootstrap-select to package.json and webpack.config.vendor.js.

Comment: `npm install` will save to package.json. Take a look at the [webpack documentation](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/configuration/) for the configuration. Typically webpack will bundle your files if you import them in your code.

Comment: I have installed @types/bootstrap-select using npm command and updated it to vendor bundle which is webpack.config.vendor.js. it didnt solve the issue

Comment: code in package.json
'
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/bootstrap-select": "^1.11.0"
  }
'


**added to vendor bundle**
'
           '@type/bootstrap-select',
'

Comment: Can't help much without knowing your webpack config.

Comment: @gary What error are you getting now? Compile-time or run-time error?

Comment: the error I am getting is compile time error and the error is **Property 'selectpicker' does not exist on type IInstance.**

code is :
******************************************************************************************
'
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import $ from 'jquery-ts';
import 'bootstrap-select';


@Component({
    selector: 'home',
    template: require('./home.component.html'),
    styles: [require('./home.component.css')],
})
export class HomeComponent {

    dropdown() { $('.selectpicker').selectpicker(); }
       


}'

@saravana

Comment: never add @types packages to a vendor bundle. Never import them directly. TypeScript automatically overlays them onto the actual libraries that they specify the types for. If you import them directly, your code will not work.

Comment: @gary The issue is you are using jQuery typings from `jquery-ts` which I think does not work with the typings for `bootstrap-select`. Uninstall `jquery-ts` and install the typings from `@types/jquery`. Use it in code as `import * as $ from "jquery";`

Comment: Types for `bootstrap-select` are also available via NuGet: https://www.nuget.org/packages/bootstrap-select.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped  
Just type `Install-Package bootstrap-select.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped -Version 0.0.7` in *Package Manager Console* :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 isDevBuild = process.argv.indexOf('--env.prod') < 0;
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var extractCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin('vendor.css');

module.exports = {
    resolve: {
        extensions: [ '', '.js' ]
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)(\?|$)/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000' },
            { test: /\.css(\?|$)/, loader: extractCSS.extract(['css']) }
        ]
    },
    entry: {
        vendor: [
            '@angular/common',
            '@angular/compiler',
            '@angular/core',
            '@angular/http',
            '@angular/platform-browser',
            '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
            '@angular/router',
            '@angular/platform-server',
            '@type/bootstrap-select',
            'angular2-universal',
            'angular2-universal-polyfills',
            'bootstrap',
            'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css',
            'bootstrap-select',
            'bootstrap-select/dist/css/bootstrap-select.css',
            'es6-shim',
            'es6-promise',
            'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css',
            'jquery',
            'jquery-ts',
            'zone.js',
        ]
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'wwwroot', 'dist'),
        filename: '[name].js',
        library: '[name]_[hash]',
    },
    plugins: [
        extractCSS,
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ $: 'jquery', jQuery: 'jquery' }), // Maps these identifiers to the jQuery package (because Bootstrap expects it to be a global variable)
        new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
        new webpack.DllPlugin({
            path: path.join(__dirname, 'wwwroot', 'dist', '[name]-manifest.json'),
            name: '[name]_[hash]'
        })
    ].concat(isDevBuild ? [] : [
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ compress: { warnings: false } })
    ])
};
```